# saving file using JFileChooser at any location

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

hello i am trying to save the file at location specified by Jfilechooser  the situation now is when user click on save the file is created on the project direction with the name title but what i need is to give the user option where to save the file and choose the name he like using JFileChooser

```
if(buttonPressed.equals(save)){

         File myFile = new File("title");
         final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
         int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
         fc.setSelectedFile(myFile);
         if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

            try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(myFile)) {   

            for (int i =0 ; i< cModel.getRowCount(); i++)
            {
               sData.add(cModel.getValueAt(i, 1).toString());
               eData.add(cModel.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
               tData.add(cModel.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());
               writer.println(i+1 + "\n");
               writer.println(sData.get(i)+" --> " + eData.get(i));
               writer.println(tData.get(i));
               writer.println("\n");
            }
            }catch(FileNotFoundException ioEx){

            } 

         }

         }
```

Comment: You probably want something like `fc.setSelectedFile(myFile); int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(buttonPressed); myFile = fc.getSelectedFile();`

Comment: @GuillaumePolet no that is not working

Comment: Then provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because here it's working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
JFrame choose = new JFrame();
choose.setTitle("Save To ...");
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(choose);
```